# New to Firebase. Many warnings in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I'm trying Firebase for the first time, and after adding `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`, Xcode 9.0.1 produces many warnings in the various cocoa pod installed libraries.

> Possible misuse of comma operator (in leveldb-library)
>   Multiple build commands (for a file in BoringSSL (there are like 15 copies of internal.h)

In gRPC-Core there are 51 issues, some "multiple build commands" and several that I've read about elsewhere relating to syntax, like "This function declaration is not a prototype".

I'm new to Firebase and Cocoapods, and I'm just starting a project that I would not need to ship for weeks.  What should my strategy be:

a) These warnings are due to the Firebase pods not catching up with new language rules.  I should just wait for some time and reinstall and they will go away.

OR

b) I goofed up installation (even though I've tried several times), and there's a step I missed, or a step I shouldn't have taken.  Here's what I did:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'  // all this worked fine up to here
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

1. added no new code to the boiler plate stuff I copied in to test auth
2. closed xcode
3. $pod install
4. open xcode, clean, rebuild, see 107 warnings

I can live with the warnings and carry on developing, should I?  It will be hard to see legit warnings my code generates, and if (when) my newbie code hits an error, I'll be stuck wondering if it's me or one of these warnings manifesting itself.

Can someone share experience?  Is it some bad install thing I did or is it just that I'm using stuff that's too new?  More importantly, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is (a).

Xcode 9 introduced several new default warnings and the Firebase team is working with its dependency pod providers to address them.

You can expect the warnings to go away in upcoming Firebase, leveldb, and gRPC releases.